# Difference between SessionBean and SessionAttribute

Tags: spring, session, attributes, javabeans

What is the difference between `SessionBean` and `SessionAttribute`, what is the best way to add an object to a session? For example:

**SessionBean:**

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session")
class A {
    ...
}
```

**SessionAttribute:**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    A a  = new A();
    session.setAttribute("A", a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They're very similar and both of those objects can be retrieved through `HttpSession` object.

The only difference between them is that SessionBean will be injected by Spring and session attribute will be added to session by programmer using [HttpSession#setAttribute(String, Object))](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method.

I would use SessionBean if you know that this bean would be required in session and you also know all required state or the behaviour of the bean and SessionAttribute when you receive the information in runtime.